# RStudio frozen and not working even after a reinstall

Tags: r, rstudio

I was using pivot_wider() on a fairly large grouped data which led to RStudio being frozen. I understood that i must ungroup the data before using the pivot_wider command.

However, the problem is that now my RStudio window is frozen. I have uninstalled and reinstalled both R and RStudio to correct the issue. But even after reinstalling RStudio opens and the Global Environment tab keeps buffering till the whole window goes blank.

Please let me know how i can fix the issue.

[Attaching a screenshot of the window when i open RStudio.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Ws6j.png)

Comment: Try this: https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200534577-Resetting-RStudio-Desktop-s-State

Comment: Thank You. This worked. I think the main issue was not renaming/deleting the hidden preferences and files.